# Unable to render the HTML page in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to return the HTML page on the success of login but unable to render in the web.

When I press the <kbd>SignUp</kbd> button it should render sign_up_otp_pop_up.html in UI.

Also
In the browser's response (inspect element) I can see the sign_up_otp_pop_up.html code.

Do I need to do add in urls.py or views.py in Dashboard?

The sample folder structure of my project:

- login

  - views.py
- Dashboard

  - templates

    - dashboard

      - sign_up_otp_pop_up.html

Following API takes few inputs from the user and verifies it by OTP which is sent on the user's mobile.

sign_up_otp_pop_up.html code.

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        body = json.loads(body_unicode)
        api_key = body["api_key"]
        if api_key == settings.API_KEY:
            signup.fullname = body["fullname"]
            signup.user_class = body["user_class"]
            signup.email = body["email"]
            signup.phone = body["phone"]
            signup.username = body["email"]
            user_exist = Users.objects.filter(email=signup.email).exists()
            if user_exist == True: 
                return JsonResponse({
                    'text':'User already Exist',
                    'status': 401,
                    },status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
            else:  
                url = "https://sample.url.com/api/v5/otp?authkey="+settings.AUTH_KEY+"&template_id="+settings.TEMPLATE_ID+"&mobile="+signup.phone
                response = req.get(url)
                content = 'OTP sent successfully'
                return render(request, 'dashboard/sign_up_otp_pop_up.html', {'content':content})
```

Comment: Can you share the error message

Comment: @Oussama I am not getting any error or warning on the terminal as well on the browser console.

Comment: Can add the error message (from the terminal)  to you question. So that we can help you find the error. The error message holds the clues usually

Comment: I think more details are needed  for example if login=='Success'

Comment: @Oussama I have added few lines of code and some descriptions. I hope that can help you. sorry but there is no error on the terminal or console.